# How can I access a custom UserControl added to a TabPage in a TabControl - C# -?

Tags: c#

I have a class called MainAreaTab which inherits from UserControl.

In a different user control (called Page3), I have a TabControl which contains TabPages, and every TabPages contains a MainAreaTab. This is the code where I do this and it works fine:

```
string mainAreaString = mData.GetMainAreaName((UInt32)mainAreaId);
MainAreaTab myUserControl = new MainAreaTab(mData, (uint)mainAreaId);
TabPage mainAreaTabPage = new TabPage(mainAreaString);//Create new tabpage
mainAreaTabPage.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
mTabControl.TabPages.Add(mainAreaTabPage);
```

As I said, this work fine. The problem comes when I want to access a public method of every MainAreaTab in every TabPage. I tried something like this but it does´t work:

```
foreach (TabPage tabPage in mTabControl.TabPages)
{
  TabControl userControl = (TabControl)tabPage.Controls[0];
  MainAreaTab tab = userControl as MainAreaTab;
}
```

The error I get is:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl' to 'MainAreaTab' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion.

Am I missing something? Can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that you want `MainAreaTab tab = (MainAreaTab)tabPage.Controls[0];`. Try that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use LINQ to grab all `MainAreaTab` controls from all `TabPage`'s in one go.

```
var mainAreaTabs = mTabControl.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>()
                              .SelectMany(pg => pg.Controls.OfType<MainAreaTab>());
```

Then loop through the collection like this:

```
foreach (var tab in mainAreaTabs)
    tab.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks. That really helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, I believe you want to try the following:

```
foreach (TabPage tabPage in mTabControl.TabPages)
{
    MainAreaTab tab = tabPage.Controls[0] as MainAreaTab;
}
```

What this does is:

```
foreach TabPage in TabControl
    get the TabPage's MainAreaTab
```